how to set the fixed position and set off the auto zoom of the orbitControls in React Three Fiber?
hey i have this react three fiber model i get from sketchfab i set the orbit controls but the position  of the object/models is not fixed and every time i try to scroll through my it automaticaly zoom and i can't scroll down. Do you have any solution to this ?
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber"
import Models from "../components/Models"
import { Suspense } from "react"
import CanvasLoader from "../components/CanvasLoader"
import { OrbitControls, PerspectiveCamera } from "@react-three/drei"
import { Stage } from "@react-three/drei"



const Hero = () => {

  return (
    <section className="min-h-screen w-full flex
    flex-col relative">
        <div className="w-full mx-auto flex
        flex-col sm:mt-36 mt-20 c-space gap-3">
            <p className="sm:text-3xl text-2xl font-medium
            text-white text-center font-generalsans">
                Hi, I am ------  
                &nbsp;<span className="waving-hand ">
                    
                </span>
            </p>
            <p className="hero_tag text-gray_gradient">
                A Full-Stack Developer
            </p>
        </div>

//The CANVAS DIV
        enter image description here
    </section>
  )
}

export default Hero

i want to set off the auto zoom and set the models position fixed to the center
<div className=" flex justify-center items-center absolute
        inset-0">
           <Canvas className="w-1/2 h-1/2 ">
           <Stage preset={"rembrandt"} intensity={1} environment={"sunset"}>

/* My First Solution didn't Work At All*/
           <OrbitControls enableZoom={false}/>
                <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader />}>
                <PerspectiveCamera  makeDefault position={[0,0,100]}/>
                
                    
                    <Models scale={3} position={[0,-5,0]}/>
                    
                    <ambientLight intensity={1} />
                    <directionalLight position={[100,0,10]} intensity={2}/>
                    

                </Suspense>
                </Stage>
           </Canvas>
        </div>

i already tried to set the 'enableZoom' to false but here before scrolling it still didn't work

What you are experiencing has little to do with OrbitControls, CameraControls etc. per se. If you disable the zoom, everything works fine... you just don't zoom and the camera doesn't respond to the event. It mainly comes down to the topography of your layout. Keep in mind that Canvas is part of your HTML, and like other sections in your DOM, it follows the same rules. There are several approaches to this topic and each one depends on how Canvas should behave. In full-sized experiences, usually Canvas fills the viewport and all movement happens inside. In others, Canvas is just part of the layout, and that's what you seem to be getting at. You can achieve this by wrapping Canvas and CSS.
JSX
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      {/* Section before Canvas */}
      <div className="scrollable-stuff">
        <h1>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h1>
        <p>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
        <p>ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</p>
        <p>dddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
        <p>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</p>
      </div>

      {/* Three/R3F Canvas */}
      <div className="canvas-container">
        <Canvas>
          <color attach="background" args={["black"]} />
          <OrbitControls
            enableZoom={false}
            enablePan={false}
            maxDistance={0.01}
            enableDamping={true}
          />
          <Box position={[0, 0, -2]}>
            <meshBasicMaterial color="red" />
          </Box>
        </Canvas>
      </div>

      {/* Section after Canvas */}
      <div className="scrollable-stuff">
        <p>fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
        <p>gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</p>
        <p>hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

CSS
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.app-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.scrollable-stuff {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.scrollable-stuff h1 {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.scrollable-stuff p {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.canvas-container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

CODESANDBOX
